# How to disable or remove export option in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

we want to restrict users from exporting the data they access via phpmyadmin.

So, how to remove or disable EXPORT option from phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide what you're trying to protect against and what sort of measures are "good enough." Since any user that can display information can, at a bare minimum, manually copy that data, you can't fully restrict them from getting a copy of your data.

If all you want to do is hide the Export tab, that's easy — set up a new user group (from the "[User groups](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html#configurable-menus-and-user-groups)" tab while in the "User accounts" area), remove the Export option on that page, then add all of your users to that group.

However, that's not going to stop a motivated user; they can still display data or use standard MySQL commands to create an export, so you have to decide whether it's appropriate for use in your situation.

To use the User Groups feature, you first have to have set up the [phpMyAdmin Configuration Storage](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables) (which has a zero-configuration feature, so you might not need to do much work; I still prefer to create the tables and user manually, though). Once you have the proper database and tables for phpMyAdmin to store its own configuration data, you'll get access to the second tab of the User accounts page as shown here:

[image: User accounts tab with user groups active]

From there, you can use the "Add user group" link to create a user group, giving them whatever functionality you desire and excluding the Export option. Once you've saved those changes, go back to the main "User accounts overview" page and for each user you wish to restrict, assign them to that group.

[image: User tab with a user who has a group assigned]

Remember that it's better to prevent actions using the MySQL permissions when available; so if you want to prevent a user from deleting data it's better to do that by modifying the user itself rather than through a user group. That way, it's a MySQL restriction and the user can't directly enter an SQL statement or use some other program to bypass the phpMyAdmin user groups.

Comment: Thanks Issac! Where can I find that user group option in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I linked to the documentation but not only did I fail at it, I failed to notice. I've added a lot of information to my answer which hopefully answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

We followed the patched approach, here is what we did -

- Removed `server_export.php` and `db_export.php` php files from PhpMyAdmin root path.
- Then remove the navigation links from `libraries/classes/Menu.php` by deleting lines -

```
"$tabs['export']['icon'] = 'b_export';",
"$tabs['export']['link'] = 'server_export.php';",
"$tabs['export']['text'] = __('Export');",
"$tabs['export']['link'] = 'db_export.php';",
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `PHPMyAdmin v5.2.1`, I was able to do this by renaming the file `libraries/classes/Export.php` to `libraries/classes/eeee.php`

```
cd phpMyAdmin-5.2.1-all-languages/libraries/classes
mv Export.php eeee.php
```